# Webpack public path

Tags: webpack, react-router-dom

I'm struggling to set the webpack to always point to the root path

Basically, if I visited http://localhost:8080/path ( this one finds the index.html)
and it will look for assets in `http://localhost:8080/public/assets/bundle.js`

But if I do have multiple paths like http://localhost:8080/path/1 it can't find it since it will look `http://localhost:8080/**path**/public/assets/bundle.js`

Is there a way to always set the is to the root directory(`http://localhost:8080/public/assets/bundle.js`)? even if I visit any routes? Ideally, it should NOT append the /path

I have catch all already added:

```
app.get(
  '/*',
  (req, res) => res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, DOCS_PATH, 'index.html'))
);
```

My webpack

```
const webpack           = require('webpack');
const path              = require('path');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

const assetsDir       = path.resolve(__dirname, 'docs/public/assets');
const nodeModulesDir  = path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules');
const indexFile       = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/app/index.js');

const SPLIT_STYLE = true;

const config = {
  devtool: '#source-map',
  entry: {
    app: [
      'babel-polyfill',
      indexFile
    ],
    vendor: [
      ....
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path:     assetsDir,
    filename: 'app.bundle.js'
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test:     /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude:  [nodeModulesDir],
        loader:   'babel-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use:  SPLIT_STYLE
          ? ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
            fallback: 'style-loader',
            use: [
              {loader: 'css-loader', options: { importLoaders: 1 }},
              'postcss-loader'
            ]
          })
          : [
            'style-loader',
            {loader: 'css-loader', options: { importLoaders: 1 }},
            'postcss-loader'
          ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use:  SPLIT_STYLE
          ? ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
            fallback: 'style-loader',
            use: [
              { loader: 'css-loader', options: { importLoaders: 1 } },
              'postcss-loader',
              'sass-loader'
            ]
          })
          : [
            'style-loader',
            {loader: 'css-loader', options: { importLoaders: 1 }},
            'postcss-loader',
            'sass-loader'
          ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(eot|woff|woff2|ttf|svg|png|jpe?g|gif)(\?\S*)?$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader:  'url-loader',
            options: {
              limit: 100000,
              publicPath: '/public/assets/',
              name: '[name].[ext]'
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    getImplicitGlobals(),
    setNodeEnv(),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('app.styles.css'),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name:     'vendor',
      filename: 'app.vendor.bundle.js'
    })
  ]
};

/*
* here using hoisting so don't use `var NAME = function()...`
*/
function getImplicitGlobals() {
  return new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $:      'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery',
    jquery: 'jquery'
  });
}

function setNodeEnv() {
  return new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env': {
      'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('dev')
    }
  });
}

module.exports = config;
```

Comment: Actually, the only think that is configure webpack regarding public path is set in you configuration properly, `publicPath: '/'`, can you check what you get in the **source-code** of the page that you navigate to?

Comment: Your right it was the path on my index.html. Thanks!